# How to redirect outgoing external email ID to different email ID in sendmail

Tags: sendmail

I have an old server where i created lot of scripts and setup email in those scripts to be delivered to an external mail account user (name@sub.abc.com). this user are not local email user.

Now i have sendmail configured and needed to redirect mail generating with TO address: name@sub.abc.com  to get redirected to external domain (ext@ext.com).

Is it any way i could achieve this with sendmail as mail server.  because i dont remember exact location of scripts which consist email as name@sub.abc.com. Hence, i am looking for smart way to do this with sendmail configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't crystal clear, but you can forward e-mail via sendmail:

- Edit /etc/mail/aliases
- Add this:

  - 'your local username':  'external email address'
  - ex: root: test@example.com
- Run newaliases
- Restart sendmail

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know aliases can do that.  user: "name" of domain "sub.abc.com" is not local. the account name@sub.abc.com itself is an external account.  can we redirect an external email account to different email account via rewrite rule ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer (I realise the original question is old but there will be others searching) is to create a file /etc/mail/mailertable containing the line:

```
.    smtp:user@domain
```

where user@domain is the address to redirect to. The '.' at the beginning of the line represents any e-mail address at all as the key to which the mailer and the address are the value.

After saving the file execute:

```
cd /etc/mail && makemap hash mailertable < mailertable
```

and restart sendmail.